# Constructing thread executing a member function of a derived class

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance

I have two classes `Base` and `Derived` inheriting from each other. In `Base` I want to create a thread executing the member function `Handle` of the class (`TThread` is MT library of ROOT). I want to override this handle function in `Derived`, but my program always executes the function from the base class rather than the one from the derived class. How can I change it so that the overridden Handle is executed instead?

Here is the code:

```
#include "TThread.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        thread = new TThread("BaseClass", (void(*)(void*))&Handle,(void*)this);
        thread->Run();
    }
private:
    TThread *thread;
    static void* Handle(void *arg)
    {
        cout<<"AAAA"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(){}
private:    
    static void* Handle(void *arg)
    {
        cout<<"BBBB"<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{   
    Derived *b = new Derived();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Handle` virtual as [@ComicSansMS says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24208200/923854), and introduce a static member function to handle the virtual dispatch correctly:

```
#include "TThread.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() : thread() {}
    ~Base() { wait(); }

    void wait() {
        if (thread)
        {
            thread->Join();
            delete thread;
            thread = NULL;
        }
    }

    void start()
    {
        thread = new TThread("BaseClass", &Dispatch, this);
        thread->Run();
    }

private:
    TThread *thread;

    virtual void Handle()
    {
        cout<<"AAAA"<<endl;
    }

    static void* Dispatch(void *arg)
    {
        static_cast<Base*>(arg)->Handle();
        return NULL;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() { start(); }
    ~Derived() { wait(); }
private:
    virtual void Handle()
    {
        cout<<"BBBB"<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{   
    Derived b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it compiles but still Base::Handle is executed instead of Derived::Handle.

Comment: @user2923525 There is a race between the child thread running and the main thread destroying `b` in main, resulting in undefined behavior. Effectively, the main thread was stopping to `join` the child thread in `~Base`, where the object's dynamic type is `Base` instead of `Derived`, so that the child thread calls `Base::Handle` instead of `Derived::Handle`. It's the exact same problem as calling `start` at construction, but in reverse. Solved in the same way, by calling `wait` in `~Derived`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to achieve polymorphism with on a non-`virtual` function.

The reference to `Handle` in your base class constructor gets resolved at compile time to always point to `Base::Handle`, no matter what the concrete type of the object at runtime will be. This can be fixed by changing `Handle` from a `static` to a `virtual` function.

The other problem is that you are trying to create the thread from the base class constructor. The derived object has not been fully constructed at this point, so you cannot polymorphically dispatch to `Derived::Handle`, even if you change it to a `virtual` function. A quick solution for this would be to move the thread construction to a `Base::startThread()` method and call that after the constructor has returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I try to change Base::Handle to virtual  I got these errors: "must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address" and "cannot cast from type 'void *(Base::*)(void *)' to pointer type 'void (*)(void *)'". Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2923525 Sorry, I forgot to address that issue. Fortunately, [@Casey gave the missing information in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24209679/577603) in the meantime.